# How to access public static class from a windows form

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, static-methods, windows-forms-designer

I hope that my question is relevant to be answered because I'm a newbie.

For example, I have two coding named with `Class1.cs` and `Form1.cs`. Basically, Class1.cs is the program where the process of image filtering is occured, meanwhile in `Form1` is the program where I allow it to load an image from a file.

Is it possible for me to access `Class1` from `Form1` right after I click on the button to process it?

> **Class1.cs**

```
public class Class1
{
    public static class Class1Program
    {
        // My program for image filtering is starting here
    }
}
```

> **Form1.cs**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
     public Form1() => InitializeComponent();

     private void LoadImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // My program here is to open up a file image right after I click on this button
     }
     private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        // Here is the part where I don't know how to access the program from "Class1.cs".
        // I'm expecting the image that I've load before will be able to filter right after I clicked on this button
     }
 }
```

I'm wondering if there is a need to add or edit some program on the "Program.cs".
I'm hoping that my question can be answered. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of these two things:

1.You can access data in `Class1` by using static variables:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Class1
    {
        public static int Class1Variable;
    }
}

namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void LoadImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load image logic
        }

        private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1.Class1Variable = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

2.You can create an instance of Class1 inside Form1:

```
namespace MyProgram
{
    class Class1
    {
        public int Class1Variable;

        public Class1()
        {
        }
    }
}

namespace MyProgram
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Class1 c1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            c1 = new Class1();
        }

        private void LoadImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Load image logic
        }

        private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            c1.Class1Variable = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the text format. I don't know why the code blocks are not formatted as they should. If I have time later I will try to fix the format.

Comment: Thank you. Nice explanation. I will take note about this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add one property and a method to the static class for make it understandable. Let the `Class1Program` looks like the following:

```
public static class Class1Program
{  
    public static int MyProperty{get; set;} // is a static Property
    public static void DoSomething() // is a static method for performing the action
    {
        //my program for image filtering is starting at here
    }

}
```

Now you can access the method and property inside the `Form1` like this:

```
 private void ResultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Class1.Class1Program.MyProperty = 20; // assign 20 to MyProperty
    int myint = Class1.Class1Program.MyProperty; // access value from MyProperty
    Class1.Class1Program.DoSomething();// calling the method to perform the action
 }
```

Comment: Thank you sir, I've tried just now and it goes well. But now I got problem because I have too many methods that need to be declared under the main static method.